# Different nuget-packages loaded when using MSBuild than building using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I also posted this question on the microsoft forums:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/249621/different-nuget-packages-are-used-when-compiling-u.html

Consider following .csproj file:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
     <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   </PropertyGroup>
    
     <ItemGroup>
         <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows'"/>
         <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
     </ItemGroup>
 </Project>
```

Except for the files generated by visual studio when creating the project, there are no other files in this project. The generated files (except the .csproj file) are not altered in any way.

[image]

As you can see in the image, visual studio will - for both projects - reference the 11.0.1 version, and also build the executables using the 11.0.1 version.

When using the Command Line with MSBuild

```
<msbuildpath> <projectpath> /restore
```

The executables will be generated with the 12.0.3 version for the .net5.0 target and with the 11.0.1 version for the other target(s)

When using nuget.exe /restore from the command line it will also generate the assets file to use 12.0.3 for .net5.0 and 11.0.1 for the other targets.

Why is there a difference between the packages using visual studio and nuget/msbuild?
Is this expected behavior or is this a bug?

*As a side note, the problem does fix itself when using choose/when tags

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
     <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   </PropertyGroup>
    
     <Choose>
         <When Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows'">
             <ItemGroup>
                 <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
             </ItemGroup>
         </When>
         <Otherwise>
             <ItemGroup>
                 <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
             </ItemGroup>
         </Otherwise>
     </Choose>
 </Project>
```

- No matter which build-method generates the correct output, i would expect for MSBuild and VS to generate the same output. Or am i wrong?
- Why is there a difference between the packages using visual studio and nuget/msbuild?
- Is this expected behavior or is this a bug?

Comment: I'd guess that in the original case there's ambiguity. The 11.0.1 could be interpreted to be used for .NET 5.0 (and other targets) because there's no condition. MSBuild/VS may be choosing use first or last reference in the case of ambiguity. With `Choose` you've removed the ambiguity completely  -- both VS and MSBuild have to play by the same rules.

Comment: @Kit Indeed, i also suspected VS chose the 11.0.1 version because of the ambiguity, But it still doesn't explain why there is a difference between the builds generated by VS and the builds generated by MSBuild. I would still expect the builds to be the same. Even after generating the builds a few times using both methods, the differences stay the same.

Comment: True. Not sure how to account for that. I imagine there are different properties being set in different contexts, but can't say for sure beyond that vagueness without digging into it ;)

Comment: @Truesteel86, this is quite strange. And I have found something. Please check my updated answer. The second item is suitable for all targetframeworks and also overwrites the `net5.0-windows`. You should switch the order of the next two lines. But the issue is that why nuget restore command line is different on the first issue.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, thanks for looking into this issue thoroughly. I'll put the condition as the last statement as that will be a lot easier than changing my code to use choose/when. If i could i would upvote your anwser again :)

Comment: @Truesteel86,maybe what I said here on the answer is quite in a mess. I also updated the two reported links , and I made it very clear over there. And hope the Product Team will give us a satisfactory reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Please see the update first.

It is quite different between VS IDE Restore and `nuget restore`,`msbuild -t:Restore` command line.

And this is not the first issue which I met between VS IDE Restore and command line restore before. [See this issue which I raised a few days before](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10495).

The main problem is that the **VS IDE Restore** has a bit more problems and need to be fixed.

I have reported the issue to the Team. See [one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1324578/why-condition-is-ignored-under-multi-targetframewo.html) and [two](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10501). You can follow the issues, vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail.

**Since** the process might take a long time, for now, you have to use my workaround, abandon VS IDE restore and change to use restore command:

**1)** enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager** and uncheck these two options in case the vs ide backend keeps using ide restore to perform the wrong behavior.

[image]

**2)** right-click on the Project **Properties**-->**Build Event**--> add `dotnet restore` under **Pre-build event command line**.

[image]

**3)** close VS, delete `bin` and `obj` folder of the project and then restart your project on VS, click **Rebuild** to get what you want.

## update 1

I think the problem is quite strange. I think the problem is that:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
```

is the last item and has no condition. And it also suitable for `net5.0-windows` and `11.0.1` version is also included because it is in the last line of the item.

So  you should change to use this:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Make the condition at the last.

Or

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1'"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Give** each item a condition(like `choose, when`) to avoid the `targetframework net5.0` including the nuget package twice so that it will not lead the complex situation.

But `choose, when` like `if, else`, will only execute one item based on the condition but your first provided code is not the same and those are two **PackageReference** include items, and **MSBuild** will execute both of them  and when it executes the second line, it is suitable for both `net5.0-windows` and `netcoreapp3.1`, so `11.0.1` version will be included for `net5.0-windows`. That is normal.

## Important Analysis

**The problem is that**, **VS IDE Restore** will only show the version of the last **PackageReference** include item and use that version.

**In your side**, these are what you used:

```
<ItemGroup>
         <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows'"/>
         <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Since the `11.0.1` is the last include, so it always shows `11.0.1`. But **Restore Command line** is different and it only shows the first PackageReference include node. In your side, if you use **dotnet Restore Command line**, it will use the first node `12.0.3`. And it ignores the second line although it is true for it.

## **This is my environment:**

**In this situation**, `net5.0-windows` has two include, in order is
`11.0.1`,`12.0.3` while `netcoreapp3.1` only has `11.0.1`.

[image]

I used `dotnet restore` below under the msbuild. But it uses the first include nuget version. `net5.0-windows` uses `11.0.1` and `netcoreapp3.1` uses `11.0.1`.

[image]

When  I used **VS IDE Restore** below, it uses the last include **PackageReference** nuget version.

`net5.0-windows` uses `12.0.3` version and `netcoreapp3.1` uses `11.0.1` version.

**So** what I am curious why this behavior is different between **VS IDE Restore** and **dotnet Restore Command**.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently Visual Studio doesn't handle conditions in MSBuild scripts the way MSBuild does it and therefore produces other result. I couldn't find any information on whether or not they will fix this. Probably not as this is already going on since VS2010 according to this post.
https://medium.com/@corradocavalli/msbuild-conditions-and-visual-studio-6c5c9347cccf

As @Kit says in the comments on OP using Choose/When will resolve the issue.
<s>Anyway i'll mark this as answered until a better answer comes up.</s>